# What are the downsides of JavaScripts BigInt and when should I avoid it?

Tags: javascript

Is there a good reason, to not use BigInt?

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#Usage_recommendations):

> Coercion
>
> Because coercing between Number and BigInt can lead to loss of precision, it is recommended to only use BigInt when values greater than 2^53 are reasonably expected and not to coerce between the two types.

As far as I understand it, there is no implicit type coercion, only explicit type cast.
This doesn't look like a good reason to me.

Should I not use BigInt, when my numbers are "small"? I see no good reason to avoid it.

Comment: Number is a lot more convenient to work with for almost every conceivable purpose. `BigInt` is for... well... big integers. And I mean *big*. 2^53 is *huge*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not necessarily one recommendation. It can easily be two interrelated ones.

1. Only use `BigInt` for integers that reasonably may exceed 2^53.

   A `BigInt` isn't a general-purpose number. It's specifically for *large integers*, hence the name. They're best when used in specific, isolated cases where you expect *large integers* may well appear, in no small part because in other cases, the design goals (including preventing accidental losses of precision) make the type too restrictive to be useful. You can't do `Math` stuff with them, you can't mix types, etc. For numbers you know will be less than 2^53, a `Number` will be far less restricted (read: more useful), and generally much faster and easier to work with.

   (For an example of the performance difference, see https://jsperf.com/bigint-vs-number/5. The test at first showed a 1% difference at first in Chrome, but once your values aren't effectively constant, it's harder to hide the differences, and performance drops drastically.)
2. Don't convert between `BigInt` and `Number`.

   The entire point of `BigInt` is to serve as an arbitrary-precision integer. Converting to a `Number` takes all those extra bits you asked for, and shoehorns them into a double-precision float. Only the most significant 52+1 bits will be preserved. If you can tolerate that happening, you probably don't need a `BigInt` in the first place.

They're interrelated in that the temptation to convert gets greater the more you deal with `BigInt`s that would be better off as `Number`s and bump into the limitations of the type. The thing is, those limitations are for the most part quite intentional. You can better avoid those limitations by not using `BigInt` than by sidestepping them and throwing bits away.

Comment: “You can't do `Math` stuff with them” ok, that's a fair point. “generally much faster“ I don't say you are wrong on that one, but I want to see some benchmark or some good evidence. I could not find a good source with a quick google search.

Comment: @mogoh: Updated with my experiments.  :)

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I understand it, there is no implicit type coercion, only explicit type cast.

Indeed.

> Should I not use `BigInt`, when my numbers are "small"? I see no good reason to avoid it.

I'm not a heavy user of `BigInt` but I agree with your remark: if you rely on integers in a range that is beyond `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, you should definitely want to use `BigInt`s, for large as well as "small" integers.

Actually I guess the disclaimer in the MDN documentation should be interpreted in the other way around: if you need large integers, **try your best not to use type casts, namely, don't use `Number`s in the first place**.

This is by the way what suggests [that other paragraph](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#Description) in the MDN documentation:

> Be careful coercing values back and forth, however, as the precision of a `BigInt` may be lost when it is coerced to a `Number`.